# Android ProgressBar not updating as expected?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, tablelayout, android-progressbar

I am dynamically populating a `TableLayout` with rows using an `AsyncTask` and am not getting the expected `ProgressBar` behavior.

I initially set the max value of the `ProgressBar` to three times the number of items I'm processing to accommodate three operations. Here's my code:

onPreExecute:

```
        progress.setMax(items.size() * 3); // We need to create the rows and add listeners to them
```

Async Class

```
public class TableLoader extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Boolean>{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... params) {

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            // doStuffToCreateRow
            rows.add(row);

        progress.publishProgress();
    }
}
```

Then I have:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (!isCancelled()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
            table.addView(rows.get(i));
            progress.incrementProgressBy(1);
        }

        table.requestLayout();  

        listener.onTaskCompleted();
    }
}
```

Where publishProgress is simply:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
  progress.incrementProgressBy(1);
}
```

Finally, in my `onPostExecute method`, I have a callback to the activity that uses the `AsyncTask`, which looks like this in the main activity:

```
public void onTaskCompleted() { // TableRows have been generated
    TableLayout itemTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.itemTable);

    for (int i = 0; i < itemTable.getChildCount(); i++) {
        TableRow row = (TableRow) itemTable.getChildAt(i);
                    // Create and add a listener to that row's checkbox
                    // progress.incrementProgressBy(1);
    }
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

For some reason, the initial increment works properly and causes the `progressBar` to reach 1/3 full after its completion (generation of TableRows). Afterwards, there's a 2-5 second pause where the UI thread blocks and then the progressBar disappears, which I've set to occur after the for loop in the `onTaskCompleted` (the third and final operation) terminates. The data then shows up.

Why is my `progressBar` not updating as expected?

I've looked the issue up but have found people incrementing the bar by < 1 using division or not using the UI thread. To my knowledge, I'm updating using the UI thread and incrementing by 1/number of items * 3 each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For some reason, the initial increment works properly and causes the progressBar to reach 1/3 full after its completion**

It means the Async part is working properly, your first third is the one involving doInBackground / ProgressUpdate, that is, heavy stuff is done outside of the UI thread and just signals progress update. The UI thread is sleeping and happily waiting for update requests.

**Afterwards, there's a 2-5 second pause where the UI thread blocks and then the progressBar disappears, which I've set to occur after the for loop in the `onTaskCompleted` (the third and final operation) terminates. The data then shows up.**

The other two operations take place in the UI thread. Both **for** in `onPostExecuted` and `onTaskCompleted` run on the UI Thread and are tight loops. **The UI thread is blocked in your loops**. So while you are inside those tight loops no matter how many thousand times you mingle with any UI component: setprogress, settext, etc.... **It will not update until the for loop ends, your routine finishes, and the system takes control again of the UI thread.**

What you can do is, as it looks like there's a big number of rows, to add them in chunks then update the progress. This will give some air. Take a look at the following prototype

```
 Handler handler=new Handler();

 interface AddRowListener {
      public void onRowsAdded();
 }

 private void addRowChunk(final int startRow, final int totalRows, final AddRowListener listener) {

          for (int i=startRow; i<startRow+CHUNK_SIZE; i++) {

               if (i>=totalRows) {
                    // we have finished! Just call the listener
                    listener.onRowsAdded();
                    return; 
               }
               addView....
          }

          // After adding some rows, we end here, and schedule a call to this function again
          // to continue. The 25ms delay is optional, but it will give some air to Android for sure

          handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                addRowChunk(startRow+CHUNK_SIZE, totalRows, listener);
          }, 25);
 }

 private void addRows(AddRowListener listener) {

      TableLayout itemTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.itemTable);

      // we start the process, it will create row chunks and call the listener when done
      addRowChunk (0, itemTable.getChildCount(), listener); 
 }
```

So to add the rows you now can do:

```
 addRows (new AddRowListener() {
       public void onRowsAdded() {

           // the rows have been added.

       }
 });
```

By the way, what's your row size? it has to be huge !

PD_ You have to select a CHUNK_SIZE. Just experiment with values until the UI is snappy. I'd say 40-50 is OK, but it's just a wild guess and depends on the phone hardware.

Comment: I see - if I understand you correctly, even if I add the update to the progressBar inside of the loop that is manipulating individual rows, I still won't see the update until the UI thread is finished with the for loop. That is, not at all. Could I simply run two for loops, where the outer loop splits the operation into multiple steps and the inner loop handles the code for each row? I could place the progressBar update outside of the inner loop.

Comment: You should do that, but in order to effectively split the operation, you should return control to the UI thread somehow (otherwise you would just restructure your algorithm, but it will hijack the UI thread as well). I am expanding the answer with a prototype to do this.

Comment: I understand what you're suggesting conceptually, but I'm not yet sure how I'd do something like this. A prototype would be wonderful! Thanks for your help!

Comment: The key concept is: The UI won't update "in the middle of your routines" if they run on the UI thread.

Comment: Wouldn't I need some check to prevent the handler.postDelayed call if I've finished? My row sizes could theoretically go up to several thousand - it's pretty crazy! It's definitely not an expected use-case, but because of the nature of the app, I want to make sure it's airtight. I'll test this out and get back to you! Thanks!

Comment: yes, it's the first "if" inside the for, if `i>totalRows` we call the listener to inform completion and return, so `postDelayed` is not executed anymore.   Mind also that if you have several thousand rows, you are doing it the wrong way as you will probably exhaust Android resources. You should change to a `ListView` + adapter approach to have the benefits of **View Recycling**, so only the views on screen are actually created,  independently of the total size. So if you consistently have more than, say, 100 rows, your application performance will be much better using ListView+Adapters.

Comment: I'd considered listviews, but had heard of problems with checkboxes. My current implementation features checkboxes that allow the user to toggle the state of records in the database. If I can find a way around the checkbox issue without using a tablelayout, I'm open to that. Thanks so much!

Comment: There are no problems with CheckBoxes in listviews. I use listviews with multiple checkboxes, different item heights, etc. Whichever problem you might have heard of, it will be an easily solvable misconception !

Answer (score 0):

Don't set your `progress.setMax()` inside `doInBackground()`, do it inside `onPreExecute()` instead. You should not modify the UI thread(Main Thread) from a worker/background thread, and there is exactly where doInBackground() runs. `onPreExecute()`, `onProgressUpdate()`, and `onPostExecute()` run on the UI Thread.

Comment: I've adjusted my code to fix this problem, but it does nothing to fix the issue of the ProgressBar loading only until 1/3, freezing, then disappearing as the three steps finish. This doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: What is the output of your Log when that happens?

Comment: I'm not currently using the log explicitly myself. What would you like for me to check?

Comment: What is that progress.publishProgress() by the way? progress is your progress bar, isn't it?

Comment: Correct - publishProgress() simply contains "  progress.incrementProgressBy(1);"

Comment: First thing first, you are setting the MAX three times the items.size(), but the for is iterating just the items.size(), meaning just a third part of the total. Could that be the reason?

Comment: I may not have made my approach clear enough - three things need to happen for each row. I need to create the rows, then add them to the tableLayout in onPostExecute, then add listeners to them using a callback to solve scoping problems. Because of this, I set the max to three times the number of rows and increment the progress by 1/3 each time any operation happens. Thus, 3*numRows operations should be happening that each increment by 1. That shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using a thread to update the progress bar. This approach is perfect to update the progress........but if you want to set manually then **first set the max for progress bar** just call below method in your onPreExecute and then onPostExecute

```
 progressBar.setProgress(value);
```

Where Value should be half of the max when you are calling from onPreExecute and then cent percent from onPostExecute......but I recommend you to use a thread to update the correct progress.

Comment: Wouldn't this create an unresponsive progressbar that suddenly spikes up to half and then full? Further, I'm reading a lot of answers elsewhere suggesting AsyncTask for this very sort of thing because it's an abstraction for threading and progress. It even has an onProgressUpdate method made for this very sort of thing. Could you provide some justification for this answer? I'm open to convincing, but I'm not so sure this is the best way to approach it.

Comment: @user3563124 yes you are and i already mentioned that this is just a weird fix so only I am suggesting for progress update using thread

Comment: Very bad idea using threads. AsyncTask has publishProgress witch does all.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use publishProgress in onPostExecute. Just call incrementProgressBy.

Comment: I'll try this - why shouldn't I do that? Furthermore, the last set of calls (the listener assignment) DOES simply call incrementProgressBy, but I don't see any positive change. Why would changing the onPostExecute call change this?

Comment: Just tried this - it does not appear to solve the problem. I still get 1/3 a bar, five seconds of UI thread blocking, then a completed list and no bar.

Comment: Why don't you put all your code in doInBackground? Only in onPostExecute you could attach the new views to their parent.

Comment: From what I understand from the documentation for AsyncTask, any code that updates the UI should be executed on the UI thread. Running code from onPostExecute runs it on the UI thread. Furthermore, the callback is used to execute code in a particular scope to avoid having to pass certain variables to the AsyncTask. Either way, I'm not sure that placing that code in doInBackground (even if I could) would fix the progressBar issue.

Comment: As long as you are only creating views in doInBackground all is ok. You only touch the UI if you assign a parent. So thats what you do in onPostExecute.

Comment: If that callback only adds listeners you could call it in doInBackground.

Comment: That IS what I'm doing in onPostExecute - I iterate through my collection of created TableRows and do tableLayout.addView(row.get(i)).

Comment: The listeners are added in the callback because of scoping issues that aren't shown here - either way, the job is done, and whether the progress is incremented or not, it's not going past 1/3. It doesn't seem that changing that would make a difference.

Comment: The scoping issues stay the same I would think. How long does the whole process take? Seconds? I mean the first part. If you don't call the callback then how much less time?

Comment: About 5 seconds with 1000 elements

Comment: Please give three values for the three runs. Apparently you start with an already existing tablelayout. So you have to add 1000 items in onPostExecute. If you would create the tablelayout at runtime you could add all children in doInBackground. Then in onPostExecute you only had to add the tablelayout to its parent.

Comment: I added more of the code to the question so that you could see it. I could make the change to a dynamic tableLayout and feel that that would increase performance, but would it be likely to fix the progressBar problem?

Comment: Well i asked for three durations. It could be that it would be ok to 2/3 then. You have still setMax on the wrong place.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for when you ask for three durations - durations of what, exactly? Also, setMax was moved to onPreExecute, but I didn't change that in the question. Sorry about that!

Comment: The duration of your 'three operations'.

Comment: Each operation takes about the same amount of time - 2-5s with 1000 items/rows to handle.

Comment: You do not mind that I suggest here that maybe a nice implementation with a ListView could benefit? 1000 rows...

Comment: Got it - I'm working on making the change now. Thanks for your advice!